# Android MultiTouch does not work

Tags: java, android

```
 @Override 
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{ 
    synchronized (getHolder())
    {   
        int aktion = event.getAction();
        if (aktion == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            touched = true;
            bar.shareTouch(event.getX(), event.getY(), touched);
        }
        else if (aktion == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            touched = false;
            bar.shareTouch(event.getX(), event.getY(), touched);
        }
            if (aktion == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN)
        {
            touched2 = true;
            bar.shareTouch2(event.getX(), event.getY(), touched2);
        }
        else if (aktion == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) 
        {
            touched2 = false;
            bar.shareTouch2(event.getX(), event.getY(), touched2);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is a Code to chech if first Finger is going onto the screen or leaving it. The same for another finger.

```
public void shareTouch2(float xTouch2, float yTouch2, boolean touched2)
{
    if (xTouch2 <= gameViewWidth/2) {
        if (touched2 == true) {
            touchedLeft2 = true;
        }
        else if(touched2 == false) {
            touchedLeft2 = false;
        }
    }
    else if (xTouch2 > gameViewWidth/2) {
        if (touched2 == true) {
            touchedRight2 = true;
        }
        else if(touched2 == false) {
            touchedRight2 = false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public void shareTouch(float xTouch, float yTouch, boolean touched)
{
    if (xTouch <= gameViewWidth/2) {
        if (touched == true) {
        touchedLeft = true;
        }
        else if(touched == false) {
            touchedLeft = false;
        }
    }
    else if (xTouch > gameViewWidth/2) {
        if (touched == true) {
            touchedRight = true;
        }
        else if(touched == false) {
            touchedRight = false;
        }
    }

}

private void moveRight()
{
    x += 3;
}

private void moveLeft()
{
    x -= 3;
}
```

---

```
private void checkTouch() {
    if ((touchedLeft == true && touchedRight2 == false) || (touchedLeft2 == true && touchedRight == false)) {
        moveLeft();
    }
    else if ((touchedLeft == false && touchedRight2 == true) || (touchedLeft2 == false && touchedRight == true)) {
        moveRight();
    }
    else if ((touchedLeft == true && touchedRight2 == true) || (touchedLeft2 == true && touchedRight == true)) {

    }
}
```

The `checkTouch()` is called in the `onDraw()` Method. Now if I place a finger on the right side of the screen it moves right. Same for left. But if I touch left and the right without removing the left finger the Object still moves left although it should stop. Now when I leave the left finger it still moves left although it should move right.

I hope you understand my problem.

Hope you can help

Comment: Have you verified whether ```shareTouch()``` or ```shareTouch2()``` is being called as you touch and lift each finger? Android might not be firing the events you think it is...

Comment: What do you mean? Can you explain it?

Comment: Just make each function output something to the ADB log, and check whether ```shareTouch2()``` is really called when you touch down (and lift up) your second finger, rather than ```shareTouch()``` for both fingers

Comment: Okay I know what is the problem. When I touch the screen with Finger 1 it recognizes it. When I touch with Finger 2 it recognizes it too. But then when i have 2 Fingers on the screen and lift one up it always says that i lifted the second Finger, even if I lift the first. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just assume the `ACTION_POINTER_UP` Event will only be sent for the same finger `ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` was sent.

Just as the `ACTION_DOWN` event is always fired for the first finger to touch down, the `ACTION_UP` event is only fired for the *last* finger to lift (i.e. when there are no more fingers on the screen). All others will get an `ACTION_POINTER_UP` event, even if it's the finger that started the gesture.

However, the Android documentation does [specify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)

> Each pointer has a unique id that is assigned when it first goes down [and] remains valid until the pointer eventually goes up.

So in theory, your first and second finger should still have the same ID, regardless whether the Event that reports them.

The solution is simple, then: Use [getPointerCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerCount%28%29) and [getPointerID()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerId%28int%29) to keep track of your fingers.

This may be easier if you refactor your code to account for more than two fingers by replacing the Booleans `touchedLeft` and `touchedLeft2` with a single counter, e.g. `fingersOnLeftSide` - which has the neat side effect of only needing one `shareTouch()` method and otherwise reducing redundancy in your code.

**EDIT:**

Disclaimer: This is just off the top of my head, untested and written without knowledge of any of your code other than what you posted. Not necessarily the best way to solve your problem, but the shortest I could think of.

This is the Event handler:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    synchronized (getHolder())
    {   
        int aktion = event.getAction();
        if (aktion == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || aktion == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
        || aktion == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || aktion == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP)
        {
            bar.clearTouches();
            for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
                bar.shareTouch(event.getX(i)); // we don't need the y coordinate anyway
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The rewritten `shareTouch()` to go along with it, as well as `clearTouches()` I introduced to make this simpler:

```
private void shareTouch(float x) 
{
    if (x < gameViewWidth/2) {
        fingersLeft++;
    } else {
        fingersRight++;
    }
}

private void clearTouches() 
{
    fingersLeft = 0;
    fingersRight = 0;
}
```

And finally, the new `checkTouch()`:

```
public void checkTouch()
{
    if (fingersLeft > fingersRight) {
        moveLeft();
    } else if (fingersRight > fingersLeft) {
        moveRight();
    }
}
```

Comment: See my edit :) Sorry, I don't have the time for a more in-depth example that actually keeps track of the fingers, but as long as checkTouch isn't called *while* the event handler runs, it should work fine.